# Can regular integrals be solved with integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration-by-parts

Can integration by parts be used to integrate functions such as $f(x) = x^3$ or $f(x) = \frac 1x$?

I know that there are simple formulas that can be used to integrate functions of those forms already, but could we use integration by parts?

I tried integrating $f(x) = x^3$ with integration by parts, where $u = x^3$ and $dv = dx$. But it ended up being an infinite loop of integrals, although, I may have done something wrong.

The reason I bring this up is because I saw an example where the integral of $\ln(x)$ was solved to get $x\ln(x) - x$ by using integration by parts where $u = \ln(x)$ and $dv = dx$. So shouldn't we be able to apply this technique to other integrals where $dv = dx$?

Comment: What do you mean by "regular integral" ??? (Please don't reply with "functions such as".)

Comment: People try to solve integrals in simpler ways with some trick or anything like that. Why do you want to solve simple integrals in cumbersome way?

Comment: I think - anything that can be integrated can be integrated by parts - seems to me that if a function can be integrated into another function, then you can always integrate is using integration by parts, since the integral you obtain when performing integration by parts, then must itself have an integral - whether or not a person finds that easier to do that way isn't really mathematics (although that's  psychology, all psychology is biology, all biology is chemistry, all chemistry is physics, all physics is mathematics)

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I know that we should try to do things in a simpler way, but I'm simply wondering if what I proposed is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every case,

$$\int f(x)\,dx=xf(x)-\int xf'(x)\,dx$$

and this is useful when $xf'(x)$ is easier to integrate than $f(x)$.

---

In the case of powers of $x$, you indeed seem to circle in rounds because the integrand keeps being the same, but you work around the circularity with

$$\int x^r\,dx=x\,x^r-r\int x\,x^{r-1}\,dx$$ and
$$\int x^r\,dx+r\int x^r\,dx=(1+r)\int x^r\,dx=x^{r+1}.$$

Notice that this doesn't work for $r=-1$, which is precisely the case where the logarithm enters into play. (In some sense $x^0\equiv \log x$.)

Answer (score 2):

To integrate $x^3$ by parts with $dv=dx$:
$$
I=\int x^3\,dx=\int 1\cdot x^3\,dx=x\cdot x^3-\int x\cdot 3x^2\,dx=x^4-3I+C
$$
and solve for $I$
$$
4I=x^4+C\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad I=\frac{x^4}{4}+\text{constant}.
$$

Comment: Okay, that's what I got too. However, this isn't quite the clean answer (1/4)x^4. Is there a way to get a clean answer much like in the case of ln(x)? And is it the case that I could use integration by parts to solve any regular integral?

Comment: What does a clean answer mean?

Comment: @user3567004 Not sure what you mean by clean answer. Do you mean right away without solving any equations?

Comment: The way to get the clean answer is to *choose* from the infinite set of solutions the one where the constant equals 0.

Comment: @user3567004: sorry but this concept of a "clean answer" is bogus.

Comment: You could probably find a class of funtions f(x) which you could transform to g(x) h(x), where either g(x) or h(x) is a finite polynomial. However, that class would probably not include all "regular" functions, for some value of "regular".